# How do I have a local computer load a virtual machine guest OS residing on the server?

Tags: virtualization

I'm not sure how to ask this.  I have a Dell 7010, and I wanted it to run a virtual machine.  VMWare, Xen, or other software.

But what do I install on the client PC so they can load the virtual machine from the server?  VMWare Desktop looks like it is for developers that need to go back and forth between OSes for testing.  I don't know what software type I am looking for.

I know I don't need VMWare Fusion or Parallels (pretty sure anyway).  I want a "blank" computer that has to get its OS (Windows 7) from the server.  I do not know where to begin and thought if I new what this was called, I could search.  How do I load that guest OS on the server on my PC?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to have some sort of hypervisor installed before you can run a virutal machine. For the use case you are proposing you sound more like you're asking to netboot your workstation.

There are apps that will let you do either, although it's not easy to netboot Windows unless you're using Windows PE.

Comment: After more reading, I think I need VDI.

Comment: Or a terminal server. You can also use most of the hypervisors to run a VM where the files are on a network share. Using NFS or SMBv3 this is faster than you would think, a lot of big virtual server environments are set up this way because it's convenient. Just beware of the performance impact on your servers...